# Displaying an object in local storage ONLY upon logging in

Tags: javascript, local-storage, display

I am doing a school project on creating a web site. I have managed to save user data into local storage upon signing up for an account. when I tried with the following codes yesterday, the codes could work: 
the key 'currentUser' would appear in the local storage after I have logged in as a user. However, after I cleared my local storage (too many users in array) and I re-run the codes again the currentUser would no longer show up in local storage. 
Here are my codes:
From edit profile page:
    `

```
<script>
var currentUser=null;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",loadUserData);

function loadUserData() {
currentUser = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
if(currentUser!=null) {
currentUser = JSON.parse(currentUser);

    }
}
</script>
```

The above codes plus this from the login html shows the currentUser as the key in local Storage (should only appear upon logging in as current user)
From login page:

```
    function checkUser(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          var status=false;

          var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
          var password = document.getElementById("password").value;


          for(var i=0;i<userList.length;i++) {
            var u=userList[i];
            console.log(u.username);
            console.log(u.password);
            if (u.username==username && u.password==password){
            status=true;
            currentUser=userList[i];
            break;
            }
          }

          if (status==true){
            location.href="EditProfile.html";
          }

     }
```

I've asked my friend, she said that the way I referred to my username and password was incorrect, and that I need to rewrite most of my codes?

Answer (score 0):

**While Signing in User You need to store in localStorage. And as the User is log out you should clear localStorage CurrentUser Key.**

Something like this:

```
  function checkUser(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var status=false;
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;


      for(var i=0;i<userList.length;i++) {
        var u=userList[i];
        console.log(u.username);
        console.log(u.password);
        if (u.username==username && u.password==password){
        status=true;
        localStorage.setItem('CurrentUser', username);
        currentUser=userList[i];
        break;
        }
      }

      if (status==true){
        location.href="EditProfile.html";
      }

 }
```

Use this to remove key from localStorage when user log out.

**localStorage.removeItem(key);**

Comment: hi, thank you for your suggestion, the currentUser did appear in the local storage, however in the value it only shows the username. How do I make the currentUser into an object such that it shows sth like: {"username":"staff","name":"alice tan","password":"123"} ? what appeared in the local storage is this: staff (under value section of current user)

Answer (score 0):

You are using local storage of HTML5 which can not store the data more than 5mb.
whenever you are using to store username and password in local storage and session storage its bad habit of programming. you are allowing people to penetrate in your site. try to use the session of whatever the programming language you are using for server side.
And you will destroy the session yourself then obviously you will not get the value again. so being an good programming habit use server side.

Answer (score 0):

simply do this

```
function checkUser(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var status=false;

  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;


  for(var i=0;i<userList.length;i++) {
    var u=userList[i];
    console.log(u.username);
    console.log(u.password);
    if (u.username==username && u.password==password){
    status=true;
                    localStorage.setItem("currentUser",u);//store whole data of logged user
    currentUser=userList[i];
    break;
    }
  }

  if (status==true){
    location.href="EditProfile.html";
  }
```

}